# How to interpret the relationship between batch size and bootstrap count in a specific paper?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, natural-language, supervised-learning, active-learning

In the paper "[Active Learning for Natural Language Parsing and Information Extraction](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eml/papers/active-nll-ml99.pdf)", the author mentioned:

> In tests on this data, test examples were chosen independently for 10 trials with n = 25 bootstrap examples and a batch size of k = 25.

I wonder what's the relationship between n and k here in sampling data for each iteration. Later, the author also mentioned using n = 50 and k = 25 for another dataset, and what does that refer to?